# Send email HTML formatted with CGI - Perl

Tags: html, perl, email, cgi, content-type

I'm trying to send an email with HTML content, but it doesn't send formatted.

This is my code,

```
print OUT "To: $email\n";
print OUT "From: $pedidos\n";
print OUT "CC: $pedidos\n";
print OUT "BCC: $tecnico\n";
print OUT "Subject: $subject\n";
print OUT "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\n\n";
print OUT "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC '-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN'>"; 
print OUT "<html><head><title>Title</title></head>";

(...more html...)
```

Any idea?

Thanks!

Comment: [Courriel::Builder](http://p3rl.org/Courriel::Builder) [Email::Sender](http://p3rl.org/Email::Sender)

Answer (score 1):

Well, for one thing, you left out

```
print OUT "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
```

without which your Content-type header doesn't mean anything.  I'm assuming that content going to `OUT` is correctly being emailed.